# IIS COM component failure - Azure VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, com

I am working on a website that uses Sage 50 Interop component dll and it all works fine in VS and my local IIS but on Azure VM IIS it throws an error.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

I have been at it for days now and have no idea what else to check or configure.

Note: I had an older version of this DLL and it worked well. All the newer versions are throwing this error on Azure.

Comment: This error RPC_E_SERVERFAULT is a very generic COM error and means the COM "server" (here your Sage 50 interop component) which runs out-of-process here has a problem and doesn't answer COM calls or fails in a middle of one. Typically, it's a bug in that component (crash, communication problem, threading issue, security, etc), and it doesn't seem too strange because an Azure environement can be quite different than a "regular" one, so you should contact the vendor.

Comment: Thank you. Strange is that the component works on local IIS and if it was a problem with the component itself then it wouldn't have worked on local IIS. 
I am fishing for some settings and environment change issues I might have on Azure VM. 
What is different?

Comment: When I reread your post you talk about Azure *VM* (my initial understanding was an Azure App Service). In a VM it should be quite similar in fact, but the rest of my comment stands: it's an issue in the component itself.

Comment: "Note: I had an older version of this DLL and it worked well. All the newer versions are throwing this error on Azure" is also indicating a potential bug by the vendor if they ever support you on Azure VM.

Comment: Since your website works fine locally, and newer versions of the DLL throw this error on Azure. You should seek support from component suppliers. Whether the new version of the component requires additional support to work on Azure VM.